# Custom props is undefined in React router-4

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react. I create a route

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/login" exact render={(props) => (<LoginPage test="hi" {...props}/>)} />
    <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={DashboardPage}/>
    <Route  component={LoginPage}/>
</Switch>
```

And in LoginPage when I try to use `console.log(this.props.test)` it is showing undefined.

Please help me what is wrong in my route.

LoginPage.js

```
import React from 'react';

import styles from './../styles/_login.css'

class LoginPage extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
      console.log(this.props.test)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      console.log(this.props.test)
    }

    render(){
        return(
          <div>I am login form</div>
        )
    }
}

export default LoginPage;
```

Comment: can you post your loginPage component code.

Comment: Please see LoginPage.js is added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure this is the case but you got two routes for `LoginPage`.
This one:

```
Route path="/login" exact render={(props) => (<LoginPage test="hi" {...props}/>)} />
```

And this one (no props passed down):

```
<Route  component={LoginPage}/>
```

I think you are on the wrong route (make sure you got `/login` in the url).

Are you sure this was intended?

**Edit**

> The one without route path will be loaded by default

You did not pass `test` as a prop to this route so that's why it is showing as `undefined`.

Comment: For any wrong route I want to navigate to login page.

Comment: Nope. The one without route path will be loaded by default

Comment: but as i mentioned in my answer you did not pass `test` as a prop to this route so that's why it is showing as `undefined`

Comment: Tats y my doubt too.. Are you checking the page without routing to '/login'.  It seems silly.. But sometimes it happens

Comment: This is the problemo. Thanks a lot. I am from Angular2 background. Need to learn React fast. <Route render={(props) => (<LoginPage test="hi" {...props}/>)} /> did the job

Comment: `The one without route path will be loaded by default` , OP is using switch so if nothing matched in the above routes then the one without path will be rendered. Otherwise the answer is absolutely correct